# EXCEL formula. Don't know where to start

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a very large spreadsheet and need to figure a way to search for specific cases-- I normally do it manually but there are 20k rows and I can't handle it manually. I know there has to be an easier way, but I don't know where to start. I'm a newbie and would really really appreciate any help.

I have a spreadsheet with the following columns:

DISEASE/DATE_REC/ACCESSION_NUM/LNAME\FNAME\AGE\SEX.

I have about 20k samples (ACCESSION_NUM) that I need to sort through. I only want to keep samples in which a patient (same LNAME, FNAME, and sex) have had a sample associated with both: disease= dysplasia AND disease= carcinoma.

So- I'd want to find cases where my data looks like this:

dysplasia/2/1/2000/12345/Smith\Jane\40\F

carcinoma/2/1/2005/568951/Smith\Jane\45\F

Any help or tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried just using AutoFilter? Select your whole table and press CTRL + SHIFT + L. Then on each header you can play with the filters to find the cases you want.

Comment: Why not just use the filter and the show only the two disease you are interested about?

Comment: Hire a programmer. Tell them to build a dictionary with the first name and last name as the key and increment the dictionary item if the disease is dysplasia or carcinoma. After the dict is built, loop through it and remove all entries where the item is not 2 or more. Finally, split the keys into a 2D variant array and use them to AutoFilter on the first and last name columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try filtering your data like in this example: https://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/filtering-data/1/

Comment: Thanks for your help! I actually figured it out-- I ended up having to use a vlookup formula to find cases from the same patient. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it!